# Query regarding pandas

Tags: excel, pandas, python-3.8

Even after installing xlrd module, I am not able to read excel files using pandas, every time it's showing file directory not found. Please help!
I am using " import Pandas as pd"
" data=pd.read_excel("notebook.xlsx")
It shows error as file not found

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is not finding the excel file. Try to put the complete path on the read_excel function like `read_excel("C:/documents/notebook.xlsx")`.